# Problems with Payable function in Solidity. It is correctly executed in Remix, but it is not executed at all from Web3 Javascript core

Tags: javascript, frontend, solidity, web3js

I have one of my public functions in a solidity smart contract programmed as a payable function. This one is supposed to receive ETH when it is called from a user perspective, and then execute the corresponding internal lines of code.

The problem I find is that it is correctly executed in Remix. I am able to send some ETH and then click the function, and funds are transferred to the smart contract and the function is executed correctly, as expected.

However, when I the try to do the same in Javascript, everything looks to run ok (no error messages at all), Metamask is opening as normal, but at the end I realise I'm only sending the ETH amount to the smart contract, but the function is not executed at all!

Solidity code:

```
function PlayGame () public payable {...}
```

Web3 code

```
let result = await DappContract.methods
    .PlayGame()
    .send({ from: from, value: weiamount });
```

Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

I tried changing web3 syntax several times, and changing solidity version, but nothing works.

Comment: Is doing through metamask creating a transaction?

Comment: Yep! In fact, the transaction completes correctly from a metamask perspective. I even receive an object in the "result" variable.

Comment: Is the transaction a success?

Comment: Yes it is! It is a success, and I can see the smart contract in solidity increasing the amount of ETH received!

Comment: Then why do you think that your smart contract function is not executed?

Comment: Well, I have some internal counters which are not being updated, which makes me almost confirm that the function is not being executed. For example, I have a "betcounter" which is increased every time the function is executed, and it remains 0 everytime I call the function from the frontend. However, it increases if I call the function from remix, so the function is working properly

Comment: It the transaction is on a public network you can use a debugger like tenderly.co to check what's happening with your smart contract transaction, transaction hash

Comment: I am using testnet right now in KCS chain right now. By any chance do you know any way to debug frontend function calls in remix directly?

Answer (score 2):

I just found out what was the problem.

It was related with the way I was importing web3.js library.

I am using plain html/javascrip code so I am really using a line of code like this one:

The problem is based on the fact that this type of import gets the "lates" distribution of web3.js and problems started when it moved from web3.js v1.x to web3.js v4.x

I have been able to recover the original functonality just by setting the specific version of web3.js to an old one, which in my case is web3.js v1.3.0 and everything works like it used to do in the past.

I hope this helps somebody else with similar issues.

Regards!